# Passing IEnumerable across appdomain boundaries

Tags: c#, .net, performance, remoting, appdomain

Is it generally a bad idea to pass an IEnumerable across appdomain boundaries?

I ask because with my current understanding of IEnumerable implementations, the enumerator isn't going to be used until the collection is, well, enumerated.  When you are crossing appdomain boundaries, particularly involving multiple processes, would this not result in multiple trips across the boundary, one for every item returned?  If that is the case, then returning the collection in its entirety, when possible, such as in an array, would be preferable in terms of performance, would it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it depends how the object to be enumerated is: whether is inherits from `MarshalByRef` or if it is serializable. In the second case, a copy is passed to the other appdomain, which then resembles the array approach. On the other hand, if it inherits from `MarshalByRef`, it pretty much depends how the enumerator is accessing the owner instance.

So in general, I'd say that you should only pass `IEnumerable`s accross appdomains if you do know what to expect. Otherwise, you may get unexpected results or bad performance.

Comment: I should have clarified that I am assuming MBR.  Given that, this answer, and the other answers, I think I will avoid IEnumerable return values unless there's a good argument in a specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, assuming `MarshalByRefObject`, it is **2** trips per item (plus one); one to `MoveNext()`, and one to `Current` (for every `MoveNext()` that returns `true`). Plus a `GetEnumerator()` call, and probably a `Dispose()`. So for a `MarshalByRefObject`, no: don't do this; use an array.

However, if it **isn't** `MarshalByRefObject` it is more interesting. For example, ADO.NET Data Services exposes data on a LINQ API (`IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T>`), but this works by building a specific query when needed, doing one round trip, and iterating back at the client.

Of course, you probably shouldn't be using *remoting* over any real distance (prefer WCF etc), so maybe the first scenario isn't a *huge* problem - you won't have *much* latency. Plus you'll either have the same latency issues on the entities (if `MarshalByRefObject`) or the serialization costs (if not).

Personally, on the **very few** occasions I use remoting (usually just to allow dll unloading), I have a `MarshalByRefObject` to represent some kind of service, and serializable entity objects. Perhaps rather predictably for me, I use protobuf-net to minimise the serialization cost.

Comment: I was just pondering about this as well, and came the same conclusions. I was trying to find a balance between a large serialized object in one go that would be filtered down in the other domain, vs passing a linq query across the domain to be executed and then have the subset serialized back. The question seems to be can you pass a linq query across the domain without negative effects (like preventing one domain from loading the others' types?). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Joe an interesting thought, perhaps: a named memory-mapped file. Have it opened by both app-domains, with separate in-process hooks to it (the enumerable parts local per app-domain). Let the OS worry about sharibg the underlying data.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll have to think about doing that. (I was just thinking about extensibility of our current plugin framework.)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is a bad idea.  An enumerator almost always keeps a reference to the collection it is enumerating.  Assuming both are serializable, you'll serialize the entire collection as well when you cross the boundary.  No round-trips though.

Answer (score 0):

yeah. it's not safe even to pass it across threads.  you'd better convert it to array to pass.

Comment: Re "safe" - as long as the threads (or `AppDomain` in this case) are well-behaved, that shoudln't be an issue; but I agree with the arrays...